# How to use acquireToken with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, azure-ad-msal

How can I use `acquireToken` - which requires a `Fragment` to be passed in - with Jetpack Compose, where I don't have a `Fragment`?

```
val parameters = AcquireTokenParameters.Builder()
    .withScopes(scopes.toList())
    .withCallback(authenticationCallback)
    .withFragment(<what can I pass in here?>) // <--------- relevant line
    .build()

_msalPublicClient.acquireToken(parameters)
```

I am on the latest MSAL for Android, version 4.1.0

Comment: How strange. The docs for `getFragment()` on `AcquireTokenParameters` describe the fragment as optional, but the activity is required. `AcquireTokenParameters.Builder` does not have an option for supplying an activity, only a fragment. 

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf .Please check my answer and try to integrate with your app and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This answer might work/not work based on the architecture of your app.

To begin with ,quite strange why microsoft requires Fragment and not sure about what is the usecase behind it.
It seems issue raised [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/1744).Have to wait for update regarding that.

Lets assume for now Fragment is compulsory. Actually we can use Fragment in compose app. Because legacy apps using xml must have support to gradual migration from fragment architecture to compose ui.By the way, Android provides that flexibility to integrate composable to legacy activity/fragment architecture.

**2 Cases .**

1. If you have single activity app architecture and all other are compose UI. You might need to do little more work to adapt fragment in compose app.
2. If the signin/signup screen where you are using msal is separate activity and for core features you have other activity , you can integrate fragment only to activity where msal is being used.

Lets jump in to implementation.

1. First thing ,you need fragment dependancy.

   ```
   implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.5.5'
   ```
2. Assuming you are having activity.

   ```
   class MainActivity : FragmentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
   }
   ```

Here your activity should extend FragmentActivity or any activity classes extending FragmentActivity. ComponentActivity may not work.
You need to have your xml file for activity and use setcontent view. You might need to create layout resource folder and layout file if not present.

3. Your activity xml.

   ```
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.MyFragment"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
   ```

Here were are having FragmentContainerView and refer to the fragment class we are going to create. No need to inflate.

4. My Fragment class.

   ```
    class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                MyApplicationTheme {
                    // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                    Surface(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                    ) {
                        CompositionLocalProvider(MyFragmentProvider provides this@MyFragment) {
                            SigninScreen("My App Name")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
   }
   ```

Here Fragment does not need xml file. Fragment will now be the root of all your compose content.  Here we are using CompositionLocalProvider to hold the fragment instance and later it can be used in multiple composables.
You can also use LocalCurrent.context and typecast to fragment. But that you might need to do everytime. Better way is to use CompositionLocalProvider.

5. You can add `staticCompositionLocalOf` outside of your fragment class in.

   ```
    val MyFragmentProvider = staticCompositionLocalOf<MyFragment> {
      error("No Fragment Instance Provided")
    }
   ```

So you can access fragment instance in any composables which are in same activity and fragment layout tree.

6. Here this is the composable function ui. Here I am getting the fragment instance and passing to MSAL.

```
    @Composable
    fun SigninScreen(name: String) {
        //Here I am getting instance of the fragment.
        val myFragment =  MyFragmentProvider.current
        Text(text = "Signin $name!")
        Button(onClick = {
            val parameters = AcquireTokenParameters.Builder()
                .withScopes(scopes.toList())
                .withCallback(authenticationCallback)
                .withFragment(myFragment) 
            .build()
            _msalPublicClient.acquireToken(parameters)
    
        }) {
            Text(text = "Signin")
        }
    }
```

The most important thing is your composable's direct parent should be fragment instead of activity. And its instance will be provided to all child composables via `CompositionLocalProvider`.  And this migration is wholly based on existing architecture and size of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try the AcquireTokenSilentParameters

```
val acquireTokenSilentParameters = AcquireTokenSilentParameters.Builder()
            .withScopes(authConfig.getApiAuthScope())
            .withCallback(authenticationCallback)
            .forAccount(account
                ?: throw MsalUiRequiredException(MsalUiRequiredException.NO_ACCOUNT_FOUND)
            )
            .fromAuthority(account?.authority
                ?: throw MsalUiRequiredException(MsalUiRequiredException.NO_ACCOUNT_FOUND)
            )
            .build()
```